# TextBox Problema con comas y puntos para convertir el texto a float

Tags: c#, conversión-de-tipos, textbox

tengo un problema respecto a los textbox quiero convertir su contenido a float
pero confunde las comas de los puntos.
Tengo el siguiente codigo

```
 textBoxX.Text = String.Format("{0:N2}", decimal.Parse(textBoxX.Text));
                        textBoxY.Text = String.Format("{0:N2}", decimal.Parse(textBoxY.Text));
                        textBoxZ.Text = String.Format("{0:N2}", decimal.Parse(textBoxZ.Text));
                        var X = float.Parse(textBoxX.Text);
                        var Y = float.Parse(textBoxY.Text);
                        var Z = float.Parse(textBoxZ.Text); Function(X,Y,Z);
```

Cuando en El TextboxX pongo "3.5" este convierte X = 35.00 sin embargo si coloco "3,5" este si convierte X= 3.50
Como puedo hacer para trasformar el punto en coma o en su defecto la coma en punto.
Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El método Parse recibe 2 parámetros, uno es el string y otro el formato. Si no le pasas formato, utiliza el del SO. En este caso, está usando el formato español de decimales.

Para que lo parsee utilizando el formato americano, le puedes pasar el formato:

```
decimal x = decimal.Parse("3.5", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

O puedes hacer que toda tu aplicación utilice el formato americano (cuidado, esto afecta también a fechas, etc.)

```
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
decimal t = decimal.Parse("3.5");
```